# How to get the messenger conversation link via Facebook graph API?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to create a hyperlink for the customer so that he can easly navigate to the facebook conversation page. I've tried to use the `{page-id}/conversations?user_id={psid}` endpoint. The response I did get was:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "t_{some_id}",
      "link": "/{some_id}/inbox/{some_id}/",
      "updated_time": "2022-08-25T15:52:04+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that the link does not redirect to the context user, but instead to the last conversation made by this page.

Could anyone help me with that?

Best Regards